# Android Custom ListView onClickListener returns null

Tags: android, android-listview, listadapter, onitemclicklistener

Something very strange is happening with my custom ListView. After the list is loaded if I click on the ListItems very fast it crashes but if I give it a second then everything works fine.

My list contains section headings (see screenshot) which changes the position of the UI list from the Model List. So when I populate the ListView I do the mapping in the listAdapter class and I believe this is causing the code the crash. I click on the view before the mapping is complete and I get a "Value" of null for the given key.

[image]

---

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements SectionIndexer {
private Context mContext;
private static final String TAG = "ListAdapter";
private LayoutInflater mInflater;
private ArrayList mData = new ArrayList();

// MapIndex to map the scroll alphabet to section
private HashMap<String, Integer> mapIndex;

// To return the right index otherwise the click will return wrong objects becasue the count the section headers
private ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer> viewPositions;

// contains all the sections alphabets
private String[] sections;

/** Int code to represent regular list items **/
public static final int TYPE_ITEM = 0;

/** Int val to represent header list item **/
private static final int TYPE_SEPARATOR = 1;

/** There are two different items **/
private static final int TYPE_MAX_COUNT = TYPE_SEPARATOR + 1;

private static TextView name;
private static TextView industry;
private static UserModel user;
private ImageView logo;
private static int mCount = 0;
public ListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<UserModel> users) {
    Collections.sort(users, UserModel.Comparators.NAME);
    viewPositions = new ConcurrentHashMap<Integer, Integer>();
    mContext = context;
    mInflater = ((Activity)mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    mapIndex = new LinkedHashMap<String, Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < users.size(); i++){

       String ch =  users.get(i).getFirstName().substring(0,1);
       ch.toUpperCase();
       /** If HashMap doesn't have the Alphabet put the new one **/
       if (!mapIndex.containsKey(ch)){
        mapIndex.put(ch, i);
        addSeparatorItem(ch);
        mCount ++;
        }
        addItem(users.get(i));
        viewPositions.put(mCount,i);
        mCount ++;
    }

    Set<String> sectionLetters = mapIndex.keySet();
    sections = new String[sectionLetters.size()];
    sectionLetters.toArray(sections);

}

public int getRealPosition(int key){
    Log.d(TAG, "getRealPosition: Key = " + key + "Value = " + viewPositions.get(key));
    return viewPositions.get(key);
}


public void addItem(final UserModel item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addSeparatorItem(final String item) {
    mData.add(item);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
    if (mData.get(position) instanceof UserModel){
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
    return TYPE_SEPARATOR;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
    return TYPE_MAX_COUNT;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mData.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mData.get(position);
}


@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    int type = getItemViewType(position);
        switch (type) {
            case TYPE_ITEM:
                user = ((UserModel)mData.get(position));
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_contact_list, null);
                name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_contactName);
                name.setText(user.getFirstName() + " " + user.getLastName());
                industry = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_industry);
                industry.setText(user.getIndustry());
                logo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.list_logo); 
                break;
            case TYPE_SEPARATOR:
                TextView seperator = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
                seperator.setText(mData.get(position).toString());
                seperator.setClickable(false);
                seperator.setBackgroundColor(mContext.getResources().getColor(R.color.blue));
                convertView = seperator;
                break;
        }
        return convertView;

}

/********************* SectionIndexer Methods ***********************/
@Override
public Object[] getSections() {
    return sections;
}

@Override
public int getPositionForSection(int sectionIndex) {
    return mapIndex.get(sections[sectionIndex]);
}

@Override
public int getSectionForPosition(int position) {
    return 0;
}
}
```

---

```
public class ContactListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private ArrayList<UserModel> mUserList;
private ListAdapter adapter;
private IndexableListView mListView;
public static final String CONTACT_FRAGMENT = "ContactFragment";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstances) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstances);
    setContentView(R.layout.list_layout);
    //setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    mUserList = UserList.get(this).getUserList();
    Collections.sort(mUserList, UserModel.Comparators.NAME);

    mListView = (IndexableListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
    adapter = new ListAdapter(this, mUserList);
    mListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    mListView.setFastScrollEnabled(true);
    mListView.setDivider(null);

    mListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                if (adapter.getItemViewType(position) == adapter.TYPE_ITEM) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ContactActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra(HomeFragment.LAUNCH_FRAGMENT, CONTACT_FRAGMENT);
                    intent.putExtra("userId", adapter.getRealPosition(position));
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.sort_menu, menu);
    return true;
}



@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.sortName){
        Log.d("Sort ", "Sort by Name Clicked");
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
}
```

---

```
12-10 09:47:39.951 17995-17995/com.example.macintosh.klickcard D/ListAdapter: getRealPosition: Key = 6Value = null
12-10 09:47:39.971 17995-17995/com.example.macintosh.klickcard D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-10 09:47:39.981 17995-17995/com.example.macintosh.klickcard E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.macintosh.klickcard, PID: 17995
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.lang.Integer.intValue()' on a null object reference
at com.example.macintosh.klickcard.Helpers.ListAdapter.getRealPosition(ListAdapter.java:83)
at com.example.macintosh.klickcard.ContactListActivity$1.onItemClick(ContactListActivity.java:52)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:339)
at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1544)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3721)
at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:5660)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6837)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
```

Comment: Post your stack trace

Comment: @Jas stack trace added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while to figure this out. Couple of things I found out was that don't check if convert view is null, because it messes up the organization of the list. Second was not to use a hashmap because the adapter class gets called in random times and you are mapping to wrong positions hence the null pointer exception. The trick is this method. Nothing mind blowing just a plain index shift.

```
public int getRealPosition(int key){

    user = (UserModel) getItem(key);
    String ch =  user.getFirstName().substring(0,1);

    for (int i = 0; i < sections.length; i++) {
        if (ch.equalsIgnoreCase(sections[i])) {
            return key - (i + 1);
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are creating new View element in your ListAdapter getView method every time, that might be the reason of crash. You can make use of previously created view element.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

  // Create view element only if convertView is null
  if (convertView == null) {

    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    convertView= inflater.inflate(YOUR_XML_RESOURCE_ID, parent, false);

  }

  // Populate convertView with necessary details

  return convertView;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to be the case. That's how I had it setup originally but the list repeats the elements under the wrong section. i.e puts list item from A under the last section. Also it doesn't fix the crash.